# Select newest entry for each user without using group by (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `myTable` with four columns:

```
id        UUID,
user_id   UUID ,
text      VARCHAR ,
date      TIMESTAMP
```

(`id` is the primary key and `user_id` is ***not*** unique in this table)

I want to retrieve the `user_id`s ordered by their newest entry, which i am currently doing with this query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM myTable GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC
```

The problem is that `GROUP BY` takes a long time. Is there a faster way to accomplish this? I tried using a window function with `PARTITION BY` as described here [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql), but it didn't really speed things up. I've also made sure that `user_id` is indexed.

My postgres version is 10.4

**Edit: The query above that I'm currently using is functionally correct, the problem is that it's slow.**

Comment: What do you mean with "ordered by their newest entry"? Do you want to see **only** the newest entry (what your title suggests) or **all** of them, but with some kind of special sort order?

Comment: I want **all** the user_ids, sorted by each user_id's newest date. The query above is correct, it's just slow. I'm not looking for complete entries, only the user_ids.

Comment: Then why can't you simply use `select user_id from the_table order by user_id, "date" desc`?

Comment: Perhaps i'm explaining this poorly, I want all the user_ids, but each user_id exactly one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an index on `user_id, date desc`.  That might help.

You can also try filtering -- once you have such an index:

```
select t.user_id
from myTable t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from myTable t2
                where t2.user_id = t.user_id
               )
order by t.date desc
```

However, you might find that the `order by` ends up taking almost as much time as the `group by`.

This version will definitely use the index for the subquery:

```
select user_id
from (select distinct on (user_id) user_id, date
      from myTable t
      order by user_id, date desc
     ) t
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Adding the index sped things up :). In addition, both your suggestions turned out to be faster than my current query, although the first approach gives some duplicates, presumably because some user_ids have multiple entries with the same newest date.

Answer (score 3):

Your query seems like a relevant approach for your requirement:

```
select user_id 
from mytable 
group by user_id 
order by max(date) desc
```

I would recommend an index on `(user, date desc)` to speed things up. It needs to be a single index on both colums.

You could also give a try to `distinct on`, which *might*, or might not, give you better performance:

```
select user_id
from (
    select distinct on(user_id) user_id, date
    from mytable
    order by user_id, date desc
) t
order by date desc
```

Comment: index should be on `(user_id, date DESC)`

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen: ah yes, obviously... Thanks.

Comment: I end up liking this PostgreSQL SQL extension. It's very handy.

Comment: @GMB And now, of course, I would love to be able to keep more than one row per group. Maybe somethign like `distinct (5) on (user_id)`? I know, I know. I'm asking for too much, now :D

Comment: @TheImpaler: nope, `distinct on` can't do that... In that case, you need to resort the good-old `row_number()` approach.

Comment: I want to accept your answer as well, but alas stack overflow won't let me do that :(